# for loop doesn't finish executing the whole object length?

Tags: javascript

this is an assignment in free code camp and this is my code, for loop stops on first iteration at 0,it doesn't finish cause on first iteration of for loop is true, how can I force this code to finish looping to check this array of objects' whole properties and values?

```
//Setup
var contacts = [
{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["Javascript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}
];


function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    debugger;

    // Only change code below this line
    for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
        if (!contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            return 'No such property';
        }

        if (contacts[x].firstName != firstName) {
            return 'No such contact';
        }

        if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop) && contacts[x].firstName === firstName) {
            return prop;
        }
    }
    // Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Harry", "likes");
```

Comment: Well, just stop returning no such property and no such contact and store that text in a variable if needed

Comment: of course in your first return function finishes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the loop you should only `return` when you have a match. Otherwise you should continue:

When you reach the end of the loop it means there was no match, and you can return a specific error value:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
    debugger;

    // Only change code below this line
    for (var x = 0; x < contacts.length; x++) {
        if (contacts[x].hasOwnProperty(prop) && contacts[x].firstName === firstName) {
            return prop;
        }
    }
    return 'No such contact';
    // Only change code above this line
}
```